# Incorrect input argument when calling another program via system()

Tags: visual-studio, system, filenames

I'm working on a program A.exe that was developed in Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Express. It calls another program B.exe that was developed in Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 Pro. B.exe was written by someone else.

A.exe takes as input a text file, and then passes this text file to B.exe for further processing.

All programs and input files are in the same folder.

In A.exe, I have

```
char filename[1000] = {0};
sprintf(command, "B.exe .\\%s", filename);
system(command);
```

In B.exe, I have

```
CFile finput;
CString infilename;
long dataLength;

infilename = argv[1];
if (!finput.Open(infilename, CFile::modeRead|CFile::typeText))
{
    printf("Cannot open file %s (%s)\n", infilename, argv[1]);
    exit(0);
}
else
    dataLength = (long)finput.GetLength();
```

When I ran A.exe, I get

```
Cannot open file . (.\test.txt)
```

For some reason, it only reads the first character of the argv[1] string as infilename. I have tried the full directory, e.g. C:\..., and I will still get

```
Cannot open file C (C:\...)
```

But if I run B.exe on its own, i.e.

```
B.exe .\test.txt
```

the program runs correctly.

I don't understand what is the problem here. Can anyone help me?

Comment: doubt: What does "command" represent?

Comment: @Tom: it was a character array declared `char command[500]` to store the command that is passed to `system`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with quotes around the filename ?

```
B.exe ".\test.txt"
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried `sprintf(command, "B.exe \".\\%s\"", filename);` and it still did not work.